# Format SecondaryAxis ticklabels Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, histogram

#### I am trying to generate a histogram with two y axes.

- One axis should display the frequency.
- The other should display the relative frequency as a percentage (with `%` sign on this axis).

#### Below I show two ways that I hoped to accomplish this.

- Setting `break_with_str_format = True` to format during axes generation

  - Generates `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`
- Setting `attempt_y_format = True` to format after generating the axes

  - Does not generate an error, but also does not format the axis
- Leaving the code as is will generate a histogram like the one at the bottom of my post.

```py
n_data_points = 1000

def freq_to_relfreq(x, break_with_str_format = False):
    """
    Setting `break_with_str_format` to true will generate an error
    """
    y = ((x/n_data_points )*100)
    if break_with_str_format:
        y = f"{y}%"
    return y

def relfreq_to_freq(x, break_with_str_format = False):
    """
    Setting `break_with_str_format` to true will generate an error
    """
    y = (x/100)*n_data_points 
    if break_with_str_format:
        y = f"{y}%"
    return y

def toy_hist(attempt_y_format = False, data = np.random.normal(0, 1, n_data_points), save_fig = False):
    """
    Setting `attempt_y_format` to true will not generate and error, but will not format the axis   
    """
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20, 24))
    ax.hist(data, color = "#193582",  edgecolor = 'white', bins = 50, alpha = 1)
    ax2 = ax.secondary_yaxis('right', functions = (freq_to_relfreq, relfreq_to_freq))
    ax2.set_ylabel("Relative Frequency",fontdict = {'fontsize': 40,  'family':'Calibri'}, labelpad = 15)
    ax2.tick_params(axis = "y", labelsize = 28)
    ticksy2 = ax2.yaxis.get_major_ticks()
    newy2_ticks = [f"{i}%" for i in ticksy2]
    ax.set_ylabel('Frequency', fontdict = {'fontsize': 40,  'family':'Calibri'}, labelpad = 15)
    ax.tick_params(axis = "y", labelsize = 28)
    ax.tick_params(axis = "x", labelsize = 28)
    if attempt_y_format:
        ax2.set_yticklabels(newy2_ticks)
    if save_fig:
        plt.savefig('toy_hist.png')
```

I could do something like this to get the `%` included in the axis label, rather than the ticks, but I would really prefer the `%` in the ticks.

```py
ax2.set_ylabel("Relative Frequency(%)",fontdict = {'fontsize': 40,  'family':'Calibri'}, labelpad = 15)
```

#### Thank you for you help!

[image: toy_hist_result]

Comment: It would be `set_yticklabels` instead of `set_yticklables`; but I suspect that won't work either?

Comment: Indeed, silly typo on my part. Using `set_yticklabels` doesn't generate an error, but it also does not change the secondary. I am editing the question to reflect the correct keyword.

Comment: Right, so the problem is that a secondary axis ignores the formatter. This is a limitation in the current implementation; and while I've seen several people already stuck at that point, noone has up to now openend an issue on the bug tracker for it.

Comment: Interestingly, `ax2.yaxis.get_major_ticks()` actually returns as list of `matplotlib.axis.Ytick` objects -- litterally n-ticks worth of `'<matplotlib.axis.YTick object at 0x0000020A80244978>'` at different addresses . . . so  `[f"{i}%" for i in ticksy2]` is actually creating a list of strings like `'<matplotlib.axis.YTick object at 0x0000020A80244978>%'`. This still does not explain why the secondary axis remains unaltered, but that code (if it did something) would not actually format the ticklabels like, for example, `1%`.

Comment: Do you want to know why that feature was not implemented?

Comment: Why? I was thinking it has to do with the fact that the two axes are linked by those functions, so you would need to have another layer of data-structure to handle the interface between the true values and the formatted values.

Comment: Not really. It's more that noone thought about this feature, such that currently the default formatter is restored anytime the axis is drawn.