# Draw grid line on SecondaryAxis - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

## The question

I am trying to draw grid lines from the ticks of my SecondaryAxis with

```
ax2.grid(color=color,linestyle='--')
```

nothing shows up on the figure, I believe I am in the same situation as for [Format SecondaryAxis ticklabels Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58440639/format-secondaryaxis-ticklabels-matplotlib), aren't I ?

However, does anybody have a workaround for the issue without reversing the scales ? I mean by reversing the scale is to have the percentages scale on the main axis and the normal scale on the secondary axis.

## The full code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#generate dummy load duration curve
dur=2500
load = np.random.normal(60,30,dur+1)
load[::-1].sort()

x=range(0,dur+1)

perticks = np.linspace(0,1,11)
xticks = perticks*dur

# get yticks from xticks
yticks = np.interp(xticks, range(0,dur+1), load)
print(yticks)

# create figure object with axe object
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 8))
ax1.plot(x, load)

#create second axis
ax2 = ax1.secondary_yaxis('right')

# label and color of the secondaryaxis 
perlabels = ['0%', '10%', '20%', '30%', '40%', '50%', '60%', '70%', '80%', '90%', '100%']
color ='tab:blue'

ax2.set_yticks(yticks)
ax2.set_yticklabels(labels=perlabels)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', color=color, labelcolor=color)

# draw grid lines on the secondaryaxis
ax2.grid(color=color,linestyle='--')

# do the same for x axis
ax3 = ax1.secondary_xaxis('top')

ax3.set_xticks(xticks)
ax3.set_xticklabels(labels=perlabels)
ax3.tick_params(axis='x', color=color, labelcolor=color)

ax3.grid(color=color,linestyle='--')
```

## The output

[image: plot without the grid lines]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some digging on this topic, and opened an [issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18941) on GitHub. Here's what I found out:

- The SecondaryAxis is "quite new thing", added in matplotlib 3.1.0. (May 2019). Even the [v.3.3.3 docs say](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.secondary_xaxis.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.secondary_xaxis) that the `secondary_xaxis()` method is experimental.
- The `SecondaryAxis` inherits from `_AxesBase`, which is an "[implementation detail](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18941#issuecomment-726220282)". It is not supposed (as of v.3.3.3) to work as `Axes` object, and the `SecondaryAxis.grid()` is not supposed to draw anything (like `_AxesBase.grid()` does). Although, I agree it is misleading that there is a non-working method.
- Therefore, at the time of writing, `.grid()` is only assumed to work on primaxy axes.

#### Making the blue axis primary

- Since `.grid()` only works on non-secondary axis, you make the primary axis blue, and move it to top & right.

#### Code

```py
# Take the x and y-ticks for transfering them to secondary axis
xticks_orig = ax1.get_xticks()
yticks_orig = ax1.get_yticks()

# Make the primary axis blue since we want to draw grid on it
ax1.xaxis.tick_top()
ax1.yaxis.tick_right()
ax1.set_xticks(xticks)
ax1.set_yticks(yticks)
ax1.set_yticklabels(labels=perlabels)
ax1.set_xticklabels(labels=perlabels)
ax1.tick_params(axis="both", color=color, labelcolor=color)
ax1.grid(color=color, linestyle="--")

# Draw the black secondary axis
ax2 = ax1.secondary_yaxis("left")
ax3 = ax1.secondary_xaxis("bottom")
ax2.set_yticks(yticks_orig)
ax3.set_xticks(xticks_orig)
```

[image: example]

#### Adding grid lines manually

You could add the grid lines also manually, like this

```py
xlim = ax1.get_xlim()
for y in ax2.get_yticks():
    ax1.plot(xlim, (y, y), ls="--", color=color, lw=0.5)
ax1.set_xlim(xlim)

ylim = ax1.get_ylim()
for x in ax3.get_xticks():
    ax1.plot((x, x), ylim, ls="--", color=color, lw=0.5)
ax1.set_ylim(ylim)
```

The output would look like this:

[image]

The difference here is now we draw lines on the figure which *look like* the grid lines.

Comment: Works like a charm thanks a lot. However I will leave the question open to see if someone has an clue on why grid() does not work on SecondaryAxis.

Comment: Added explanation of why the SecondaryAxis.grid() does not work, and another alternative workaround.

Answer (score 1):

To add on np8's answer, you can also use [axvline](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvline.html) to draw the lines. This has the advantage that you do not need to keep track of the y limits manually:

```
for x in ax2.get_xticks():
    ax1.axvline(x, color=color, zorder=-1, linestyle="--", linewidth=0.5)
```

Note also that you will need to appropriately transform the x-coordinate to match the transform you do from ax1 to ax2.

Also, in my case I first had to render the canvas in order for the tick labels to be generated:

```
fig1.canvas.draw()
```