# How can I display gridlines on a secondary y-axis in a Matplotlib histogram with two y-axes?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataset of students' scores and their corresponding populations, and I have created a histogram with two y-axes to visualize the data as shown in the image provided. However, I am facing an issue with the gridlines. The gridlines are visible on the left y-axis, but not on the secondary y-axis to the right.

[image]

I started by constructing a DataFrame and using the default Matplotlib style:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Set the style
plt.style.use('default')

# Create the DataFrame
sample = pd.DataFrame({
'score':[595, 594, 593, 592, 591, 590, 589, 588, 587, 586, 585, 584, 583, 582, 581, 580, 579, 578, 577, 576], 
'population':[ 705,  745,  716,  742,  722,  746,  796,  750,  816,  809,  815,821,  820,  865,  876,  886,  947,  949, 1018,  967]})
```

Then, I created a histogram with a secondary y-axis to display the data on the right y-axis:

```py
# Create the histogram
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
hist, bins, patches = ax1.hist(sample['score'], weights=sample['population'], alpha=0.7, color='steelblue', edgecolor='white')
ax1.set_xlabel('Score', fontsize=12)
ax1.set_ylabel('Population', fontsize=12)
ax1.set_yticks(hist[-1::-2])

# Set the y-axis range to start from the minimum value
ax1.set_ylim(bottom=hist.min()-100)

ax2 = ax1.secondary_yaxis('right')
ax2.set_yticks(hist[-2::-2])
```

Finally, I attempted to set the gridlines using the grid() method:

```py
ax1.grid(axis='y', color='red', alpha=0.5)
ax2.grid(axis='y', color='red', alpha=0.5)
```

However, the gridlines were not visible on the secondary y-axis. I tried using different options for the which parameter of the grid() method, such as which='both', which='major', and which='minor', but none of them worked.

Can you suggest a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in fact an interesting issue. The **short answer is: having two separate grids is not intended. (but there is a workaround)** (Why would one, this only confuses on the other axis?)

A `matplotlib.axes.Axes` object has only one [grid](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.grid.html) object and [`seconday_yaxis`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.secondary_yaxis.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.secondary_yaxis) is only a subproperty of an `Axes`-object and therefore lacks some functionality (check the type of `ax1`, which is your left axis aka. the major axis, and `ax2`, which is of type *SecondaryAxis*.) I would guess that the axis lacks of a body/canvas, and therefore can't plot a grid, even though the property can be specified.

Now having that said, the question is, how your get the desired behavior anyway. So we need to focus on the left axis as this is the only one we can work with (because it is the one with the canvas.) Let's try to set major and minor ticks and the corresponding grids:

```py
# set major ticks to ticks of the left axis (color the grid in red)
ax1.set_yticks(hist[-1::-2], minor=False)
ax1.grid(axis='y', color="red", which="major")
# set minor ticks to what you want to show on the right axis (color lines in black)
ax1.set_yticks(hist[-2::-2], minor=True)
ax1.grid(axis='y', color="black", which="minor")
```

Note that you can set major and minor ticks separately with [set_yticks](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks.html) and that the [grid](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.grid.html) also refers to both types individually.

Now putting everything together:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Create the DataFrame
sample = pd.DataFrame({
'score':[595, 594, 593, 592, 591, 590, 589, 588, 587, 586, 585, 584, 583, 582, 581, 580, 579, 578, 577, 576], 
'population':[ 705,  745,  716,  742,  722,  746,  796,  750,  816,  809,  815,821,  820,  865,  876,  886,  947,  949, 1018,  967]})

# Create the histogram
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
hist, bins, patches = ax1.hist(sample['score'], weights=sample['population'], alpha=0.7, color='steelblue', edgecolor='white')
ax1.set_xlabel('Score', fontsize=12)
ax1.set_ylabel('Population', fontsize=12)
# Set the y-axis range to start from the minimum value
ax1.set_ylim(bottom=hist.min()-100)
# open secondary axis
ax2 = ax1.secondary_yaxis('right')
ax2.set_yticks(hist[-2::-2])

# set major ticks to ticks of the left axis (color the grid in red)
ax1.set_yticks(hist[-1::-2], minor=False)
ax1.grid(axis='y', color="red", which="major")
# set minor ticks to what you want to show on the right axis (color lines in black)
ax1.set_yticks(hist[-2::-2], minor=True)
ax1.grid(axis='y', color="black", which="minor")
```

[image: Histogram with major and minor grid]

Answer (score 1):

According to this question, only the primary axis works with grid:
[Draw grid line on SecondaryAxis - Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64784834/draw-grid-line-on-secondaryaxis-matplotlib)

Is it a problem to just add horizontal lines at your desired positions?

```
for i in hist[-2::-2]:
    plt.axhline(y=i, color='red', alpha=0.5, linewidth=0.8)
```

Comment: a straight solution, thank you.

Comment: I am learning and taking efforts to choose between twinx and secondary_yaxix, they both have pros and cons. So aware of their limits will helps.